# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, function, object, replace, attributeerror

I'm using this code to try to replace a character:

```
from another_test import test_once_more
test_once_more()
question = input("1 letter ")
for letter in question:
    if letter == "a":
        test_once_more.replace("1","a")
        print (test_once_more)
```

This is the code I am using. All I want it to do is replace the `1` in this code.

```
def test_once_more():
    print ("123456789")
```

and replace it with an `"A"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The function is printing something and returns `None`. There's no way to change that after the fact.

What you *should* do is have the function return a value and work on *that*:

```
def test_once_more():
    return "123456789"
```

and then

```
from another_test import test_once_more
result = test_once_more()
question = input("1 letter ")
for letter in question:
    if letter == "a":
        result = result.replace("1","a")
        print (result)
```

although I'm puzzled why you're using a `for` loop to iterate over a string that will be a single character (at least if your user follows your request)...

Comment: thank you for the help I am not that good at python still learning in school

Answer (score 0):

You have a very simple error here; `test_once_more` is the name of your function, while `question` is the name of your string. Try `question.replace` (and fix the other similar mistake).

P.S. strings cannot be mutated in Python, so you need to assign the result of calling replace to another variable in order to see the effect of calling replace().